# When can I travel next time to Ecuador using my EU passport?

Tags: visas, passports, eu, romania, ecuador

I am Romanian and I traveled to Ecuador for 84 days (the limit of my EU passport, without visa, is 90 days).

The [official website](https://www.mae.ro/travel-conditions/31517) says that I can be in Ecuador for maximum 90 days, without visa. I assume 90 days / year, but that is something which is not specified.

Without doing any requests to officials (to extend my stay or something like that), when will be the next time when I can travel to Ecuador?

Let's assume my first time was between September 2018 — December 2018.

When is the next time when I can return to Ecuador, with my EU passport?

Comment: Are you working there? You may be asked to explain how you’re supporting yourself if you try to enter again visa-free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the lady from the airport passports office when I can go again. She said:

- I have the right to be in Ecuador for **90 days in one year**

  That means, during one chronological year, I can stay in Ecuador 90 days, even if I leave the country and come back, meaning: if I arrived in *24 September 2018*, and stay until in December, for 85 days, until *23 September 2019*, I still have 5 days to use without visa or anything, just with my passport.

  On 24 September 2018, I have again 90 days.
- If I want to extend the stay, I can make a request to get 90 days more.
- The 90 day period  is not reseting when I reenter in the country